# Can't get Demandware UX Studio installed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, demandware

Just installed Java most current version and Eclipse (Kepler) on my Windows 8 (64 bits). When I tried to install Demandware UX Studio, I always got an error message:

> Couldn't find http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio_pr/4.3

I followed the same steps and installed Demandware UX Studio in Windows 7 successfully.

Comment: Can you link/explain us the steps you followed?

Answer (score 15):

The steps outlined in Kiddo's answer are absolutely correct. However, the links have been updated as below.

From a post on the Demandware Xchange forum:

> As of Release 17.1 of UX Studio, Commerce Cloud will only support the two most recent versions of Eclipse, which are Neon and Mars. The update site URLs are:
>
> > http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.5
> >     http://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.6
>
> The update sites for older versions of Eclipse, such as Luna or Kelper, are no longer supported by Commerce Cloud.
>
> Commerce Cloud recommends upgrading to the most recent Eclipse versions to ensure that you are benefitting from enhancements and fixes made in the Eclipse distribution.

Comment: Oxygen - 4.7 does not work yet. But 4.6 installs just fine.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse, from the main menu, select `Help > Install New Software`.
Click `Add`.

The Add Repository dialog appears.
In the Name field, enter Demandware UX Studio.
In the Location field, enter the URL for your version of Eclipse:

- Kepler - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.3
- Luna - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.4
- Mars - http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio/4.5

> Important: If you are connecting to a Sandbox instance, these links
>   always reflect the correct version. However, if you are connecting to
>   a Staging, Development, or Production instance, you may need a
>   different version of Studio, as Studio is not always compatible. In
>   this case, Demandware recommends installing another instance of
>   eclipse and installing a different version of Studio. To install the
>   correct version for Staging, Development, or Production instances, add
>   "pr" to the link. For example: Mars -
>   http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio_pr/4.5

Note:

> If you are part of the EA or EP program and are installing a version
>   of studio that is not generally available on an EA/EP Sandbox. add
>   "ea" to the link. For example: Mars -
>   http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio_ea/4.5  If you are not part of
>   the EA or EP program, do not use these links, as they are likely to
>   contain a version of Studio that is not compatible with your instance.

Comment: For those coming here after the 17.1 release: these URLs are now totally deprecated and have been for some time.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me on Eclipse Mars

In Eclipse, from the main menu, `select Help > Install New Software. Click Add.`

Name: Salesforce Commerce Cloud  (Demandware)

Location: https://developer.salesforce.com/media/commercecloud/uxstudio/4.5

Answer (score 0):

A same question has been posted in XChange for MAC platform. I tried to re-install the DW on my machine which has already working DW app but I got the following results:

> Unable to connect to repository -
>   http://updates.demandware.com/uxstudio_pr/4.3/content.xml

```
Connection to http://updates.demandware.com/ refused
```

It looks the repository has some problems.

Comment: I'm also having problems connecting to the demandware repo from Eclipse Luna on OS X. Since there doesn't seem to be any alternative repos from which to grab this plugin, we're pretty much stuck :/